# Compass animation mixin with multiple animations

Tags: compass-sass, css-animations

I’m trying to use Compass animation mixin with multiple animations. Is this possible?

I’ve tried `@include animation(an-1 5s infinite, an-2 10s infinite)`, but I’m getting an error: `Mixin animation takes 1 argument but 2 were passed`.

Answer (score 1):

Your compass syntax is correct and works in the current version of compass. Maybe this wasn’t the case in a previous version.

[Demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/zeitwidrig/pen/vEvvaL)

Though you can always combine both animations into one (if both animations should use the exact same options, e.g. easing):

```
@include animation(an-3 5s ease-in infinite);

@include keyframes(an-3) {
    from {
      transform: scaleY(0);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      transform: scaleY(1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```